# Filter rows from a DataFrame with matching pairs of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logical-operators

I need to filter rows from a dataframe that include matching pairs of strings. For example if the below instance when filtered only data for IDs 1 and 2 would be kept as 3 does not have a corresponding '3 Month' for the '0 Month' entry:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,1,2,1], 'Period':['0 Month','0 Month','0 Month','3 Month','3 Month','6 Month']})
```

The OR operation can easily be used to filter for 2 strings, as below, but that does not drop the ID without the requisite pair.

```
df = df[(df["Period"].str.contains("0 Month")) | (df["Period"].str.contains("3 Month"))] 
df
```

Therefore I'm attempting to use the AND operator to address this need but that is returning an empty dataframe:

```
df = df[(df["Period"].str.contains("0 Month")) & (df["Period"].str.contains("3 Month"))] 
df
```

Comment: becasue your data is either "0 Month" or "3 Month"  , none of periods include anything like : " 0 Month , 3 Month"

Comment: I understand that, I'm trying to filter for instances where both '0 Month' and '3 Month' exist on separate rows for an ID. In the case of the example only rows for IDs 1 and 2 would be kept. Everything else would be dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` "ID" and the condition and transform `nunique` method to count the number of unique "Period"s and filter the rows with more than 1 unique "Period" values:

```
out = df[df.groupby(['ID', (df["Period"].str.contains("0 Month") | df["Period"].str.contains("3 Month"))])['Period'].transform('nunique') > 1]
```

Note that, instead of `|` you can use `isin`:

```
out = df[df.groupby(['ID', df["Period"].isin(['0 Month', '3 Month'])])['Period'].transform('nunique') > 1]
```

or combine the strings to match inside `str.contains`:

```
out = df[df.groupby(['ID', df["Period"].str.contains('0|3')])['Period'].transform('nunique') > 1]
```

Output:

```
   ID   Period
0   1  0 Month
1   2  0 Month
3   1  3 Month
4   2  3 Month
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I figured groupby might be involved, but wan't sure how to get there. The first time I've came across "transform" too, thanks for the teaching moment.